# How to extract fourbyte signatures and resulting arguments from Solidity compiler output?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, abi, solcjs

It seems that the Solidity compiler output has JSON that lists methods and their arguments as a complex nested JSON structure. How can I take parse structure and output the string and fourbyte that the https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/v1.10.15/signer/fourbyte package expects?

Answer (score 0):

The ABI does not contain the signature of the function in its pure form - it must be calculated based on the formation of the function declaration itself.

The signature of a function is defined as the first 4 bytes (8 hex characters) of the sha3-hash of its declaration string, in your example - `myFunc(bool,address,address,address[],uint)`. Spaces and tabs should be removed from the declaration. For the above example, the signature of the function will be **f6fe3edf**.

Comment: And the compiler is doing this anyway, I'm trying to extract the info from the compiler output.

Comment: To do this, you need to parse the bytecode, and it may change depending on the Solidity version.